# RubyGems Building Native Extensions Fails on Fedora 23

Tags: rubygems, fedora-23

First I Try:
 `gem install rails`

It Produces:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:336:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/hagoth/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/hagoth/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

I've installed development tools using `sudo dnf install ruby-devel`  Also tried it with `rvm requirements`  And I've spent the past five hours or so trying other obscure solutions online.  None of them seem to have worked.  Is there some simple obvious solution that I'm missing? I'm fairly sure the dependencies are there.  Though I may be wrong.

Running 32 bit version of Fedora 23 if that means anything.

**Update:**

The contents of `/home/username/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri/mkmf.log` are:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I.  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fPIC  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m32   -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc "
gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Comment: I am aware that there are many questions of this nature on Stackoverflow.  Most of the ones I've seen haven't solved my issue and have to do with dependency resolution.

Comment: Says `Check the mkmf.log file for more details.` What does _that_ say?

Comment: @mattdm Added to the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not *quite* sure why the package's build script is looking for the particular file it can't find, but it's provided by the `redhat-rpm-config` package. I'm pretty sure that should be on Fedora Workstation by default. In any case, since you are building software on your system, I'd suggest making sure the following groups are installed:

```
sudo dnf groupinstall development-tools rpm-development-tools c-development
```

That will solve this particular problem, and will ensure that you have other basic "native" build infrastructure tooling installed.

Comment: I actually just solved it.  Using info at this link: https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/gems-installation.html

Comment: It has kind of the same effect.  I'll give it to you.

Answer (score -1):

I addition to the answer of @mattdm, its solves fail of:

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-livbirt`

cause there is some package dependency problem . so using above command will solve that !